# dotCMS edit a menu

Tags: dotcms

I cannot figure out how to edit a menu in dotCMS.  I have been assigned the task of removing an item off a menu.  If I login to dotCMS and navigate to the URL it will show the page integrated with the CMS.  It shows a up-down arrow box for adjusting the order of the menu items.  I cannot, however, find how to add/remove/rename the items.  If I click on the up/down arrows it forwards me to a menu-reordering page.  It does not give any links to further manage the menu from there.  I did some searches in Website > Links without any luck.

[image: Screenshot of page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pages or directories are included in te menu if it has the option "show on menu" checked. You can uncheck it by going to the website tab in the cms and right click on te page or the directory you want to exclude. Click on properties in the context menu and in the new page uncheck the "show on menu" checkbox. The checkbox could be on the second tab, just look for it there, you'll fin it easy enough. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep it was the directory.  I went to Edit Folder then deselected "Show on Menu". Thanks.